# Addition of PCM Audio Files - Mixing Audio

Tags: audio, pcm, mixing

I am posed with the task of mixing raw data from audio files. I am currently struggling to get a clean sound from mixing the data, I keep getting distortion or white noise.

Lets say that I have a two byte array of data from two AudioInputStream's.  The AIS is used to stream a byte array from a given audio file. Here I can playback single audio files using SourceDataLine's write method. I want to play two audio files simultaneously, therefore I am aware that I need to perform some sort of PCM addition.

Can  anyone recommend whether this addition should be done with float values or byte values?  Also, when it comes to adding 3,4 or more audio files, I am guessing my problem will be even harder! Do I need to divide by a certain amount to avoid this overflow? Lets say I am adding two 16-bit audio files (min -32,768, max 32,767).

I admit, I have had some advice on this before but can't seem to get it working! I have code of what I have tried but not with me!

Any advice would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Also, my main issue is what the size of my mixed array should be? Should it be the size of the largest audio file to mix?!

Comment: Hello lvaan! 

You would indeed need to be careful when summing multiple signals as anything that sums over the min/max threshold will add noise/distortion. 

Do you need to solve this as a real-time problem or can it be pre-computed (non real-time)? 

For non real-time, have you also tried normalising the audio?

You can sum with either byte or float value. I would recommend converting values to float at the start to a range -1 and 1 to keep things simple/understandable

I believe for equal power summing you should multiply summed signal by (1/sqrt(2))^(n-1), for n signals.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reponse! 
For now, I have been trying to implement non-real-time. I am aware that I need to clip my values to the min & max representation of an n-bit number. I indeed have been trying addition with normalized float values from -1 to 1. 
So if I want to add two byte arrays worth of data in to one byte array, I will be doing the the sum or all index positions and adding this function to the results as you have said ( (1/sqrt(2))^(n-1), for n signals ). Can you confirm why and where you have found this calculation?

Comment: My problem is that I want to play an  output track as appose to single audio files. However, I don't know how big the array of data in the output should be (obviously different audio files for addition are of different sizes).

Comment: Hello Ivaan, I am a little uncertain wether that calculation would be accurate. I am extrapolating a little bit from https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/14754/equal-power-crossfade?noredirect=1&lq=1 and the concepts of constant power panning http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~music/icm-online/readings/panlaws/index.html  and quoting from that "**Main idea**: for power or intensity we use 10log10 _ratio_ but for amplitudes we must use 20log10(_ratio_)". The last part I think is a typo and should read 20log10(√ _ratio_ )

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decibel has a handy list of power and amplitude ratios at the top of the article

Comment: The power equations are a better match than linear values for modeling perceived loudness. If needed, the power transforms can be applied to the inputs prior to their addition. But I think the OP would be best advised to get the simpler linear addition of signals working first.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you everyone.

Comment: I have now managed to get audio addition working!

Answer (score 5):

First off, I question whether you are actually working with fully decoded PCM data values. If you are directly adding bytes, that would only make sense if the sound was recorded at 8-bit resolution, which is done less and less. These days, audio is recorded more commonly as 16-bit values, or more. I think there are some situations that don't require as much frequency content, but with current systems, the cpu savings aren't as critical so people opt to keep at least "CD Quality" (16-bit resolution, stereo, 41000 fps).

So step one, you have to make sure that you are properly converting the byte streams to valid PCM. For example, if 16-bit encoding, the two bytes have to be appended in the correct order (may be either big-endian or little-endian), and the resulting value used.

Once that is properly handled, it is usually sufficient to simply add the values and maybe impose a min and max filter to ensure the signal doesn't go beyond the defined range. I can think of two reasons why this works: (a) audio is usually recorded at a low enough volume that summing will not cause overflow, (b) the signals are random enough, with both positive and negative values, that moments where all the contributors line up in either the positive or negative direction are rare and short-lived.

Using a min and max will "clip" the signals, and can introduce some audible distortion, but it is a much less horrible sound than overflow! If your sources are routinely hitting the min and max, you can simply multiply a volume factor (within the range 0 to 1) to one or more of the contributing signals as a whole, to bring the audio values down.

For 16-bit data, it works to perform operations directly on the signed integers that result from appending the two bytes together (-32768 to 32767). But it is a more common practice to "normalize" the values, i.e., convert the 16-bit integers to floats ranging from -1 to 1, perform operations at that level, and then convert back to integers in the range -32768 to 32767 and break those integers into byte pairs.

There is a free book on digital signal processing that is well worth reading: Steven Smith's "The Scientists and Engineers Guide to Digital Signal Processing." It will give much more detail and background.

Comment: Hi Phil, thanks for the response. 
I am working with 16-bit audio & I am also implementing 24-bit audio. I have managed to get a stereo split working so that I can play just left and just right. I am aware that first two bits/3 bits and second two bits/3 bits is for left and right respectively for 16bit/24bit audio

Comment: The data that I am using is 16-bit signed little endian  for tester as this works best with Javasound - I will be looking at decoding and transforming data types at a later date

Comment: I have indeed converted my audio from bytes to float normalised between -1 and 1.  Mr problem is that I am trying to implement for non-real time audio. So I want to simple add one byte array of data to another (just 2 for now). The two byte arrays represent a stream of audio data through AudioInputStream. The problem is that these two audio files are of different byte array size. Therefore, when I add them, I am unsure what the size of my output byte array should be?? Should it be the size of the largest audio file, and append 0's to the shorter audio file ??

Comment: To confirm: with 16-bit, two bytes combine to one value left, two bytes combine to one value right, alternating. With 24-bit, three, not two are combined. Second point, do NOT add the byte arrays! Instead, add the float arrays. Third point, use corresponding frame count when adding unequally sized arrays. If you need to append 0's to make your arrays the same length in order to do array addition, that should give the correct result.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you Phil, I have the result I need now. 
It turns out I was adding byte for byte, however, I needed to store two bytes as a 16-bit number , then transform, to float and then do the addition.

Comment: When you same frame count, I presume you mean the current amount of bytes read. Terms like frame rate, frame count and anything to do with frame have confused me a little. I was only aware that sample rate and bit depth were of significance to me.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it to work! When I used the term "frame count" my intention is to be referring to the data after it has been converted to PCM floats, not to the count of bytes.